# Why doesn't this get function receive the variable car?

Tags: php, post, get

***quick_searches.php**

This code items that similar to a search done on a previous page. Then is supposed to save the specific brand listed to car.

```
<?php
    include 'header.php';
?>
<h1>Search Page</h1>
<p>Could change to OR for broadness</p>
<div class="article-container">
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit-search'])){
        $time = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['time']);
        $brand = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['brand']);
        $cars = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['cars']);
        $location = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['location']);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM classic_cars WHERE time LIKE'%$time%' AND brand LIKE '%$brand%' AND
             cars LIKE '%$cars%'AND location LIKE '%$location%'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $queryResult = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        echo "There are ".$queryResult." results!";

        if ($queryResult > 0) {

            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                echo '<a href="test.php?car = '.$row['brand'].'">
                <h3>'.$row['brand'].'</h3></a>
                <p>'.$row['time'].'</p>
                <p>'.$row['brand'].'</p>
                <p>'.$row['cars'].'</p>
                <p>'.$row['location'].'</p>  
                ';
                }
        } else {
            echo "There are no results matching your search!";
        }
    }
?>

</div>
```

***test.php***

This section of code is supposed to get car = '.$row['brand'].' from quick_searches.php and display it.

```
<?php
echo $_GET['car'];
?>
```

Comment: Is a variable 'car' showing in the URL of the page you're viewing?
$_GET array contains parameters passed into the page in the URL string - e.g. example.com/test.php?car=audi&model=A4

Would have two parameters of 'car' and 'model' accessible through the $_GET[] array.

Comment: Yes. The url is http://localhost:8080/classiccars/test.php?car%20=%20Ford

Comment: In the test file, do a `var_dump($_GET);` before the echo to see what the array contains. I would say remove the spaces surrounding the `=` in the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your URL has spaces around the parameter values - these have been URL Encoded to %20.

If you `url_decode()` the URL you'll see:

```
localhost:8080/classiccars/test.php?car = Ford
```

If you can update the URL to not have those spaces that would be preferable.
Alternatively try requesting `$_GET['car ']` rather than `$_GET['car']` and be sure to `trim()` your value returned to take the space away from the beginning.

Generally much preferable to not have spaces in a URL if you don't need them though and have control to change things.